# Difference between jboss 6 and jboss 7 standalone server?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I was using Jboss 6 . I am wondering to see jboss 7 which does not have many folders that jboss 6 had. It will be helpful if someone explains the difference between the jboss 7 stand alone server and the previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS7 is different in a lot of respects to its predecessors AS6,5. So it wont be possible to list down all the differences here.

to list  supported technology related differences, refer to below table.

[image]

Some Major Differences: (Thanks for @Jyore for additions)

1. Modular (on-demand) class-loading
2. Addition of domain managed nodes (multiple JVM management)
3. All configuration is done in `Standalone.xml` for standalone mode and `domain.xml` for domain mode.

About the new  DIRECTORY Structure

1. configuration : Configuration files for the standalone server that runs off of this installation. All configuration information for the running server is located here and is the single place for configuration modifications for the standalone server.
2. data :Persistent information written by the server to survive a restart of the server
3. deployments: End user deployment content can be placed in this directory for automatic detection and deployment of that content into the server's runtime. 
   NOTE: The server's management API is recommended for installing deployment content. File system based deployment scanning capabilities remain for developer convenience.
4. lib/ext : Location for installed library jars referenced by applications using the Extension-List mechanism
5. log : standalone server log files
6. tmp : location for temporary files written by the server

Apart from that I really dont want to duplicate information on web

There is a [migration guide from AS5,AS6 to AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7). This can help you understand what are the config changes that are generally required to switch to AS7. it also points out what has significantly changed, highly recommend going through it.

Also You can read [Getting Started with AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-GettingStartedwithJBossApplicationServer7), to know AS7 better

Comment: @Mikul Goel,  Would like to add, Modular (on-demand) class-loading is really the biggest difference.  Also the addition of domain managed nodes (multiple JVM management). All configuration is done in basically one xml file, and all configuration done via the Web Console or CLI tools.

Comment: @jyore : Sure I can add all those details and theres a lot of other stuff as well , as it sounds you too know how different AS7 is from previous versions and how much could be added to this answer.. The link provided carries all that info though. Modular Class-loading is the first section on the link I have provided.

Comment: @Mikul Goel, yes, it is a complete rewrite! I know there is way too much to list and those links are very useful in understanding the differences.  Just wanted to add a couple quick items that are new and very big differences in the versions :)

Comment: @jyore : Yup you are very right, and I would go ahead and include them in the answer, just for quick reference. Really appreciate your additions.